# Last three article module with specific layout in Joomla

Tags: css, module, joomla

I try to make a Joomla Module that I can integrate using Sp Page Builder. The module should only show the last three or four articles in a specific category "events", and list them in a row, each one in a different div, with image, title, like in blog page.

I tried to make the module and also tried to give it a class and put CSS:

```
.custom-articles .article-item {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.custom-articles .article-item img {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.custom-articles .article-item .article-info {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.custom-articles .article-item .article-title {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.custom-articles .article-item .article-date {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.custom-articles .article-item .article-intro {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

**On MVC**

You should try to getdata from db and limit them by 4 or 3 in model on your module..
Then load or inline the css on the view.

**Oldschooll**

You can put all these around 50 line php and html source in singgle default.php on ur module name..

**The Joomla Way**

There is layout option
Override module like mod_article_newflash or anything similar.
Just do custom source on folder html in ur template folder..

Comment: Since you are a Joomla dev, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and contribute your insights there too.